# PHP str_replace Any Combination of Spaces

Tags: php, regex, string, replace

I want to make sure that the `/` character in a string is always padded with a single space on both sides.

For PHP I'm currently using `str_replace` but I can't guarantee all scenarios for any number of spaces.

```
$original = "Yes/No";

echo str_replace("/", " / ", $original) . "\n";
echo str_replace(" /", " / ", $original) . "\n";
echo str_replace("/ ", " / ", $original) . "\n";
```

I know that the first parameter/argument I passed on to the `str_replace` function is wrong because it doesn't take into account the surrounding characters.

Here's some examples that I want to achieve:

```
Original            Desired
==============================
"Yes/No" ---------> "Yes / No"
"Yes / No" -------> "Yes / No"
"Yes/ No" --------> "Yes / No"
"Yes /No" --------> "Yes / No"
"Yes  /  No" -----> "Yes / No"
```

I'm leaning towards using `regex` but I don't have an idea how to use them.

#### EDIT

Now that I think about it, maybe I could do this by collapsing the spaces? Not sure.

Comment: Is that always your expected string? if so, truncate whitespace first, then pad it.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Well no, I will be expecting other strings aside from what I have here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex based replacement:

```
$original = preg_replace('~\h*/\h*~', ' / ', $original);
```

i.e. match variable whitespaces on either side of `/` and replace by `' / '`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vB0mS0/1)

Comment: This is perfect! Works like a charm. Thanks @anubhava, I remember you helping me with another regex question I had before.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_replace( "/(\s+)?\/(\s+)?/", ' / ', 'yes/ no');
```

Broken down:

`(\s+)?` matches zero or more whitespace characters

`\/` matches the slash

`(\s+)?` matches zero or more whitespace characters

`preg_replace(a,b,c)` replaces matching bits of `c` with `b`, according to the regex in `a`.

This will fix `yes/no` (zero whitespace), `yes /no` (whitespace on one side), or `yes    / no` (uneven whitespace).

Comment: This also seem to work. So which is more efficient in comparison with the answer by @anubhava?

Comment: `\s` also matched newlines and `(\s+)?` is inefficient as compared to `\h*`. You can see # of steps on regex101 demo link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

or use a lil looop

```
while(strpos($str, "  ") !== false)
    $str = str_replace("  ", " ", $str);
```

https://3v4l.org/vYCgB

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. Plus this will only solve a subset of the issues.

Comment: regex is the way to go, just posting an alernate.